# AUCTeX: how to compile a file, which does end in '.ins'

Tags: auctex, compilation

I am playing around with some LaTeX's DocStrip package.

(For those interested: it is a LaTeX package, to create documented code, in order to write e.g. a style file and incorporate the documentation in one file.  DocStrip will Strip the Documentation and generate a clean and fast loadable Stylefile but is also able, to create an exhaustive documentation on that style file.)

To use DocStrip you usually have two kind of files: the `.dtx` containing both documentation and the code and a second file, which is similar to a Makefile.  Usually it has the file extension `.ins` to be not mixed up with normal LaTeX files.

If you want to extract the style file (or any other package), you have to run LaTeX on your "Makefile", that is

```
 latex sample.ins
```

I want to be able, to use the normal `C-c C-c` key, to start this compilation.  But AUCTeX is adding the extra file extension `.tex`, so that the real call is

```
 pdflatex -file-line-error  --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" sample.ins.tex''
```

Ho do I configure Emacs/AUCTeX to run

```
 pdflatex -file-line-error  --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" sample.ins''
```

instead?

I already tried to define the master file to be "sample.ins", but even than `.tex` is added.

Comment: Customize `TeX-file-extensions` and add `"ins"` to it, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you @ArashEsbati That worked.  Would you turn your comment into an answer, I would happily accept!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Known extensions to AUCTeX are controlled by the variable `TeX-file-extensions`:

> TeX-file-extensions is a variable defined in ‘tex.el’.
>   Its value is ("tex" "sty" "cls" "ltx" "texi" "txi" "texinfo" "dtx")
>
> Documentation:
>   *File extensions used by manually generated TeX files.

You can use the customize interface to add `"ins"` to this list or with something like this in your init file:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (add-to-list 'TeX-file-extensions "ins" t))
```